# when differences stand in the way of further contact

Tags: adjectives

What is a good adjective for differences when they stand in the way of people continuing seeing each other?

in a sentence:
"The differences are to '[adjective]' for them to continue to meet." 
or 
"Their '[adjective]' differences will cause them to grow apart."

Comment: It really depends on what *kind* of differences you're talking about (cultural, economic, religious, philosophical, etc.). If you don't have any specific type of difference in mind the only truly "generic" adjectives would effectively be tautological *(the differences are too **different**)*, but you could perhaps blur that point by focusing on *magnitude/insurmountability* rather than *divisiveness (the differences are too **great/extreme/deep-seated**)*.

Comment: Depending on the context, it would sound more natural in most cases to start that sentence with "**Their** differences..."

Comment: Consider nounifying and using *impasse*: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impasse It covers the situation you describe nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The differences are too **profound** for them to continue to meet", or
"The differences are too **stark** for them to continue to meet", or "The differences are too **pronounced** for them to continue to meet", or "The differences are too **great** for them to continue to meet".

Comment: You could add 'glaring', and perhaps 'unbridgeable', to that list...

Answer (score 1):

The closest word for your meaning is *divisive* - a statement or belief that alienates people.

Comment: Did you finish writing? The post ends with comma. It would also be improved if it quoted a source for the definition given.

Comment: Sorry. (Missed the period on the keyboard) The definition is my own, but I'm sure it would be similarly worded in most dictionaries.